# How to insert items inside listbox withing another listbox on button click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, datatemplate

I have a `Listbox` which is bound to a `DataTemplate` that has another `Listbox` on it.
On DataTemplate there is a button that I want to use for adding items to DataTemplate ListBox, but I can't find a solution to do this.

Here is my listbox:

```
<Button Width="200" Content="Add Question" x:Name="btnAddQuestion" Click="btnAddQuestion_Click"/>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <ListBox Margin="5" x:Name="lvQuestions" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateQuestionTitle}">
     </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

And this is DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateQuestionTitle">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox  materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Enter question" MinWidth="200" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}"/>
                <Button Content="+" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference ThisPage},Path=DataContext.Command}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" MinHeight="50">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox>
                        </TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

This is code behind on my page:

```
public partial class UIBuilder:Window
{
    private CommandVm _commandVm;     
        public UIBuilder()
        {
            InitializeComponent();      
           _commandVm = new CommandVm();
            DataContext = _commandVm;            
        }
        private void btnAddQuestion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            lvQuestions.Items.Add(null);
        }
}
```

I have implemented this code on my ViewModel in order to add items to datatemplate ListBox:

```
 public class CommandVm
{
    public ObservableCollection<TextBox> MyItems { get; set; }
    public CommandVm()
    {       
        MyItems = new ObservableCollection<TextBox>();
        Command = new RelayCommand<TextBox>(Execute);
    }

    private void Execute(TextBox textBox)      
    {          
        MyItems .Add(textBox);  
    }

    public ICommand Command { get; set; }
}
```

I use to catch the `Execute()` function on button "+" click command, but my code doesn't add any ListBox item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyItems` is a property of the parent view model which means that you should bind to it like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.MyItems,
     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" MinHeight="50">
```

This also means that you are using one single collection of items for all questions. Besides this obvious design flaw, a view model should not contain any `TextBox` elements. This basically breaks what the MVVM pattern is all about.

What you should do to make this example MVVM compliant is to create a `Question` class that has a collection of items, e.g.:

```
public class Question
{
    public Question()
    {
        AddAnswerCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(Execute);
    }

    private void Execute(object obj)
    {
        Items.Add(new Answer());
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Answer> Items { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Answer>();

    public ICommand AddAnswerCommand { get; }
}

public class Answer { }
```

The window's view model should then have a collection of questions:

```
public class CommandVm
{
    public CommandVm()
    {
        AddQuestionCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(Execute);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Question>();

    public ICommand AddQuestionCommand { get; }

    private void Execute(object obj)
    {
        Questions.Add(new Question());
    }
}
```

The view and the bindings could then be defined like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateQuestionTitle">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox  MinWidth="200" />
                <Button Content="+" Command="{Binding AddAnswerCommand}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" MinHeight="50">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Button Width="200" Content="Add Question" Command="{Binding AddQuestionCommand}"/>
    <ListBox Margin="5"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}"
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateQuestionTitle}" />
</StackPanel>
```

This setup lets you add individual elements to each separate question.